# why setProgressBackgroundColor can not resolve error?

Tags: java, android

In this example

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
swipeLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);
```

but in android studio I get this error :
Can not Resolve method 'setProgressBackgroundColor(int )'

but in android doc this is a public method!!
why I get this error?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to use latest support lib version (v21 at the time of writing). E.g. in gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
```

Comment: thanks, You right I replace support-v4:20.0.0 with support-v4:21.0.0
and this is fix!

Answer (score 0):

Make your you imported the SwipeRefreshLayout

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
```

and added the support library to your project.