# SwipeRefreshLayout setProgressBackgroundColor() gives strange Exception

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

When I try to change the color of my SwipeRefresh-Progressbar via the setProgressbackground() method I get the Error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1026)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:756)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView.setBackgroundColor(CircleImageView.java:118)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:454)
```

I call the method like this .setProgressBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor)). The color exists in the resources file and works well in other code.

Then I looked into the SwipeRefreshLayout file and found the method to be like this:

```
  /**
 * Set the background color of the progress spinner disc.
 *
 * @param colorRes Resource id of the color.
 */
public void setProgressBackgroundColor(int colorRes) {
    mCircleView.setBackgroundColor(colorRes);
    mProgress.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(colorRes));
}
```

and to me it seems quite strange that it calls the .setBackgroundColor() one time with just the colorRes integer and another time with getResources().getColor(colorRes) .

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: See if this fixes your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820081/why-setprogressbackgroundcolor-can-not-resolve-error

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of `setBackgroundColor` takes a color in hexidecimal form not a *resource id*.

Colors are loaded from the `/res/colors.xml` file and can be called as such:

```
setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

With `/res/values/colors.xml` containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: yep thats what I did by calling getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor) where mycolor is a color that I implemented in /res/values/color.xml

Comment: just passing R.color.mycolor gives an error at runtime

Comment: Have you imported the correct `R` into the class that shows the error. You want `com.yourapps.package.R` instead of `android.R`

Comment: still gives the same exception :/

Comment: Try cleaning the project, **Project → Clean**

Comment: I think thats not the problem because the color is working in other parts of my code...

Comment: okay it's working if i pass in just R.color.mycolor and i can start the app but I still get an error at runtime that wants me to pass in getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor) although I can start the app.

Comment: I still see the error.  I think this a bug in the API.